# How to paste value in cell based on the another cell in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 2 sheets: 1 sheet contains numbers (some are duplicated) and another sheet contains the name of that number. I need to paste the name beside every number in the 1st sheet. Example shown below:

Sheet 2: The names below are to be added to every number:

```
12345   Hardware
12548   Software 
32546   Network
85468   Development
```

Sheet 1: I need to paste the name beside every equal number. For example wherever I find the number 12345, I need paste Hardware name beside 12345 cell.

```
12345
12548
32546
85468
12345
12548
32546
85468
12345
12548
32546
85468
12345
12548
32546
12345
12548
32546
12345
12548
32546
12345
12548
32546
12345
12548
32546
```

Comment: This is not the intelligent method to link Name with Numbers since you have not shown any interrelationship between both ! For small database this can be achieved by any method like IF function but it has no relevancy.  It should like Sheet 1 have has Numbers & Sheet 2 has Name with Numbers then in Sheet 1 the formula could pull the wright Names to their Numbers !!

Comment: If the numbers in sheet1 are in column A then use the  [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) formula in column B: *=VLOOKUP(Value you want to look up, range where you want to lookup the value, the column number in the range containing the return value, Exact Match or Approximate Match – indicated as 0/FALSE or 1/TRUE)*

Answer (score 1):

This type of problem is exactly what the `VLOOKUP` function was created for.

I'll assume that your numbers are in column A of Sheet1 (beginning in row 1) and your numbers and names are in columns A and B of Sheet2. Enter the following formula in cell B1 of Sheet1 and copy it to the other cells in column B.

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!$A:$B,2,False)
```

The function works by looking up the first parameter (the number in A1) in the table in columns A and B in Sheet2 and returning the value from the 2nd column of the table. The 4th parameter (False) is only required if the table is not sorted by number.

[image]

Comment: Thanks that helped but will it be a good idea if it is fir 100 plus names that needs to pasted on 1000 of nunbers. Is there any other method?

Comment: I don't see any problem doing 1000 VLOOKUPs on a table with 100 rows. If you are changing Sheet2 frequently and find that the recalculation slows down your computer, you could turn off automatic recalculation. Or you could copy everything in Column B of Sheet1 and Paste As Value. That will fix the names in Sheet1 until you decide to enter the VLOOKUP formulas again.

Answer (score 0):

What your looking for are called Nested IF statements (full tutorial here https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-if-function).

Essentially, you need a formula in the A column that looks for values in the B column (columns and Rows are interchangeable in this example).  In this example, think of A as the destination for the data and B as the sample used to determine the answer to your statement.  Just make sure you're closing each statement with a ")" at the end (observe the sample statement houses two Nested statements and ends with 2 ")".

=IF(B1=12345, "Hardware", IF(B1=12548, "Other"))

You can continue this indefinitely and then use the plus at the lower right of the finished A1 Cell to automatically change as many rows down in the A column you wish to use.  By using this method the formulas in each A column cell filled in this manner will be directed at the corresponding B cell.  So essentially you only need to update the A1 cell then drag the plus sign down to fill the remaining A Cells (which will read "FALSE" until data is plugged into the B Column cells).

[Excel Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJLiZ.jpg)

Comment: That could be a solution too, however it gets extremely long for several entries, have a look on VLOOKUP.

Comment: There is also a limit to nesting.  This is only practical if its a very short list.

Comment: @fixer1234 Actually, the limit, which was 7 prior to Excel 2007, has been increased and is now 64. [Stack Overflow source](//stackoverflow.com/q/31688171) (and personally confirmed for Excel 2007). For speed of execution, maintainability and readability reasons (although the latter two can be somewhat mitigated by using linefeeds in the formula), it gets impractical *way* before that limit is reached.

Comment: One other point nobody's mentioned, maintaining the lookup date is easier in a list than in a long, hard-coded formula, and it only has to be maintained in one place.  If it is in a replicated formula, all of the formulas need to be replaced for a change.

Comment: Geek Guru, BTW, welcome to Super User.  Don't let the feedback discourage you.  It's great that you're trying to help, and your answer is a good quality one, even is the specific recommendation might not be the best for this problem.  It still shows the OP another approach.  Everybody here learns from each other, which is part of what makes it fun.  Keep contributing.